Установка aiogram 2.20x
Всех приветствую. Сейчас мне необходимо запустить код бота на aiogram. Но код был написан еще для версии библиотеки 2.20x.
Для установки данной версии библиотеки я удалил нынешнюю версию:
pip uninstall aiogram

Затем устанавливаю нужную версию библиотеки:
pip install aiogram==2.20

Но когда установка подходит к концу появляются такие фразы:
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for aiohttp
Failed to build aiohttp
ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toll based projects (aiohttp)

Видимо, тут что то с версией VS C++. Но она у меня установлена за все годы, включая 2022, и версия 14+ у меня есть.
На счет aoihttp не знаю. Пробовал отдельно устанавливать ее, все равно не выходит.
Помогите, пожалуйста.

Версию питона тоже ставьте нужную

(и версию ОС тоже ставьте нужную, хотя надеюсь, что до этого не дойдёт)

@andreymal, какую? У меня стоит последняя, 3.12, разве она не подойдет?

Ну вот как видите, старый aiohttp для последнего питона никто не собирал, смотрите для каких питонов он есть https://pypi.org/project/aiohttp/3.8.6/#files
